# C : what are these arguments to main?

Tags: pointers, arguments, program-entry-point

I am reading a book so I can relearn C++ and I keep seeing the following arguments to main:

```
int main(int nNumberOfArgs,char* pszArgs[]))
```

I’m not exactly sure what these arguments mean. i have done some research and I think I have a basic understanding.

I do a lot more programming in Matlab and I often create a function as:

```
function output=myfunct(varargin)
```

Where varargin is a keyword meaning any arguments. I can give it anything as an argument. myfunct(1,2,'a string',objectvariable)

"nargin" is a keyword meaning the number of arguments.

So the way I understand these arguments to the main function is sort of:

```
int main(int nargin,char* varargin[])
```

Does any of what i said make sense? Can you explain it better to me. I also don't quite understand how to use pointers and references yet.

Comment: Now C or C++? Pick one, they're different languages.

Comment: Also note that it's idiomatic to use the names "argc" and "argv", as in `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. Any other name is highly uncommon and is frowned upon.

Comment: By the way, any decent beginner programming guide would have described what those arguments mean, for example, K&R C. [(Link)](http://www.iu.hio.no/~mark/CTutorial/CTutorial.html#argc%20and%20argv)

Comment: @Adad Dayos I totally agree with h2co3 K & R is a decent one for beginners... it could have easily explained you things and trying out on your own could have been fun , trust me !!

Answer (score 3):

It's a little different. Those arguments refer to the command line arguments. So when you invoke your program from the command line as follows:

```
$ myProg arg1 arg2 arg3
```

The values of `nNumberOfArgs` and `pszArgs` will be

```
nNumberOfArgs = 3

pszArgs = {"arg1", "arg2", "arg3"}
```

Also, since you mentioned pointers, the type of `pszArgs` is `char* []` because strings are arrays of `char`s, and an array is just a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @PHIfounder I was going to say that. Also, the type of `pszArgs` is `char **`, i. e. a pointer-to-pointer-to-`char`, and it is **not** an array-of-pointer-to-`char`, because it's in a function argument.

Comment: Careful. pszArgs shoud be equal to {"myprog","arg1", "arg2", "arg3"}

Answer (score -1):

Think of it this way maybe: int nNuberofArgs declares an integer the size of the next argument.  The next argument is char* pszArgs [], This creates an array the length of your program so nNumberofArgs refers to the pointer to string (ps) with zero terminated (z), in other words create enough space to run the program